# I'm getting 100% ERROR in Blaze meter when I run my JMX script which has 3 CSV data config files

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, blazemeter, taurus

KPI log

```html
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,success,bytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,Hostname,Connect
1637689348093,392388,GenerateToken,Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException,"Non HTTP response message: Connect to reportportal.productivity.dtcisb.technology:443 [reportportal.productivity.dtcisb.technology/10.27.125.70, reportportal.productivity.dtcisb.technology/10.27.124.159, reportportal.productivity.dtcisb.technology/10.27.126.216] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)",Report_Portal-ThreadStarter 1-3,false,2976,5,5,0,3d8ec0ef127d,392388
1637689348093,392388,GenerateToken,Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException,"Non HTTP response message: Connect to reportportal.productivity.dtcisb.technology:443 [reportportal.productivity.dtcisb.technology/10.27.125.70, reportportal.productivity.dtcisb.technology/10.27.124.159, reportportal.productivity.dtcisb.technology/10.27.126.216] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)",Report_Portal-ThreadStarter 1-1,false,2976,5,5,0,3d8ec0ef127d,392388
1637689348093,392388,GenerateToken,Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException,"Non HTTP response message: Connect to reportportal.productivity.dtcisb.technology:443 [reportportal.productivity.dtcisb.technology/10.27.125.70, reportportal.productivity.dtcisb.technology/10.27.124.159, reportportal.productivity.dtcisb.technology/10.27.126.216] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)",Report_Portal-ThreadStarter 1-4,false,2976,5,5,0,3d8ec0ef127d,392388
1637689348093,392388,GenerateToken,Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException,"Non HTTP response message: Connect to reportportal.productivity.dtcisb.technology:443 [reportportal.productivity.dtcisb.technology/10.27.125.70, reportportal.productivity.dtcisb.technology/10.27.124.159, reportportal.productivity.dtcisb.technology/10.27.126.216] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)",Report_Portal-ThreadStarter 1-5,false,2976,5,5,0,3d8ec0ef127d,392388
1637689348093,392388,GenerateToken,Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException,"Non HTTP response message: Connect to reportportal.productivity.dtcisb.technology:443 [reportportal.productivity.dtcisb.technology/10.27.125.70, reportportal.productivity.dtcisb.technology/10.27.124.159, reportportal.productivity.dtcisb.technology/10.27.126.216] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)",Report_Portal-ThreadStarter 1-2,false,2976,5,5,0,3d8ec0ef127d,392388
```

When I run the JMX script which has 3 CSV data config file in JMETER it working fine, but When I run the same file in Blaze meter with (5 ur,1min duration) getting the error 443(connection timed out, browser crash)error rate is 100%. running test in private account in blaze meter

1.uploaded the 3 csv files and JMX in blaze meter

2.In the place of path of csv in csv config I have given the name of csv file not path

3.In blaze meter it shows response as***-non http***

4. I have tried every thing "Implementation" added some lines in  "user. Properties"

using the latest version of JMeter
Thanks in advance
***I have used http samplers.

JMETER LOG

```html
2021-11-23 17:42:27,293 INFO o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_US
2021-11-23 17:42:27,307 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading user properties from: /shared/.bzt/jmeter-taurus/5.2.1/bin/user.properties
2021-11-23 17:42:27,308 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading system properties from: /shared/.bzt/jmeter-taurus/5.2.1/bin/system.properties
2021-11-23 17:42:27,308 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading additional properties from: /tmp/artifacts/jmeter-bzt.properties
2021-11-23 17:42:27,309 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2019 The Apache Software Foundation
2021-11-23 17:42:27,310 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Version 5.2.1
2021-11-23 17:42:27,310 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_292
2021-11-23 17:42:27,310 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.vm.name=OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
2021-11-23 17:42:27,310 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.name=Linux
2021-11-23 17:42:27,310 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.arch=amd64
2021-11-23 17:42:27,310 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.version=4.14.225-168.357.amzn2.x86_64
2021-11-23 17:42:27,310 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: file.encoding=UTF-8
2021-11-23 17:42:27,310 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.awt.headless=true
2021-11-23 17:42:27,310 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Max memory     =4250402816
2021-11-23 17:42:27,310 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Available Processors =8
2021-11-23 17:42:27,313 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Default Locale=English (United States)
2021-11-23 17:42:27,314 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (United States)
2021-11-23 17:42:27,314 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeterHome=/shared/.bzt/jmeter-taurus/5.2.1
2021-11-23 17:42:27,314 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: user.dir  =/tmp/artifacts
2021-11-23 17:42:27,314 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: PWD       =/tmp/artifacts
2021-11-23 17:42:27,314 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: IP: 172.17.0.2 Name: 3d8ec0ef127d FullName: 3d8ec0ef127d
2021-11-23 17:42:27,314 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: user.classpath=/tmp/artifacts:/tmp/artifacts
2021-11-23 17:42:27,315 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Adding to classpath and loader: /tmp/artifacts
2021-11-23 17:42:27,315 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Adding to classpath and loader: /tmp/artifacts
2021-11-23 17:42:27,320 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='/tmp/artifacts'
2021-11-23 17:42:27,321 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='/tmp/artifacts'
2021-11-23 17:42:27,427 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
2021-11-23 17:42:27,432 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
2021-11-23 17:42:27,437 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 5.0
2021-11-23 17:42:27,443 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Loading file: /tmp/artifacts/modified_sample_report_portal.jmx
2021-11-23 17:42:27,496 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2021-11-23 17:42:27,496 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2021-11-23 17:42:27,496 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2021-11-23 17:42:27,496 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2021-11-23 17:42:27,496 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
2021-11-23 17:42:27,496 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
2021-11-23 17:42:27,544 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2021-11-23 17:42:27,545 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2021-11-23 17:42:27,545 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2021-11-23 17:42:27,546 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Starting Beanshell server (9000,)
2021-11-23 17:42:27,552 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.'
2021-11-23 17:42:27,552 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.'
2021-11-23 17:42:27,893 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Running test (1637689347893)
2021-11-23 17:42:27,951 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Report_Portal
2021-11-23 17:42:27,951 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 5 threads for group Report_Portal.
2021-11-23 17:42:27,951 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2021-11-23 17:42:27,955 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2021-11-23 17:42:27,955 INFO c.b.j.t.c.ConcurrencyThreadStarter: Start supplying threads
2021-11-23 17:42:27,960 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
2021-11-23 17:42:27,960 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to UTF-8
2021-11-23 17:42:27,960 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
2021-11-23 17:42:27,960 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
2021-11-23 17:42:27,991 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Report_Portal-ThreadStarter 1-2
2021-11-23 17:42:27,991 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Report_Portal-ThreadStarter 1-5
2021-11-23 17:42:27,991 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Report_Portal-ThreadStarter 1-1
2021-11-23 17:42:27,991 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Report_Portal-ThreadStarter 1-4
2021-11-23 17:42:27,991 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Report_Portal-ThreadStarter 1-3
2021-11-23 17:42:27,993 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: launch_names.csv
2021-11-23 17:42:28,009 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPHCAbstractImpl: Local host = 3d8ec0ef127d
2021-11-23 17:42:28,015 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPHC4Impl: HTTP request retry count = 0
2021-11-23 17:42:28,125 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.h.LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory: Setting up HTTPS TrustAll Socket Factory
2021-11-23 17:42:28,134 INFO o.a.j.u.JsseSSLManager: Using default SSL protocol: TLS
2021-11-23 17:42:28,134 INFO o.a.j.u.JsseSSLManager: SSL session context: per-thread
2021-11-23 17:43:27,978 INFO c.b.j.t.c.ConcurrencyThreadStarter: Done supplying threads
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No one will be able to help unless you provide more details like:

   - schematic view of your test plan so we could see which [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) are being used
   - [JMeter Log](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000303897-Logs-Report#h_71e88ee9-9091-40f9-85c0-99da8103971c) file
   - `kpi.jtl` from [Test Artifacts](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000303897-Logs-Report#h_b67e50b6-4b3e-498f-8b6d-8261ee2fb23d)
   - optionally `bzt.log`
2. If you're a BlazeMeter customer it may make more sense considering opening a [BlazeMeter Support Ticket](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket)

Comment: I have provided KPI and JMETER log and used HTTP sampler --can u please help me

Comment: It looks like BlazeMeter cannot reach `https://reportportal.productivity.dtcisb.technology` URL. It doesn't open from my machine as well. Services like [DownForEveryoneOrJustMe](https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/reportportal.productivity.dtcisb.technology?proto=https) state that it's not reachable as well. If you need to be connected to some form of VPN. If this is the case and you want to use BlazeMeter for testing take a look at [Private Locations](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421655-Creating-a-Private-Location)

Comment: Yes, I connected to VPN, As well working on the client location, they have created separate work space for me, And running test in the Private location. -- please help me--- Thank you Dmitri--